# cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError) in Ruby 2 running rails 3.2.11

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I am getting the above error when trying to run `rails s`.

`bundle show sqlite3` produces

`c:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32` (which means, *gasp*, I'm running it on a Windows XP machine.)

I also have:

```
group :development, :test do
  ...
  gem 'sqlite3'
  ...
end
```

I haven't found any other answers similar (environment-wise) to this one.  Any help?

Comment: Sorry for the silly question but you did run `bundle install`, right?

Comment: And you installed `sqlite3` itself properly? (Check if the command line tool `sqlite3` is available)

Comment: do you have sqlite3.dll in your PATH or wherever it needs to be?

Comment: @padde Yes on both counts, see `bundle show sqlite3` above...


@rogerdpack I presume so, since other sqlite3 databases work in the previous iteration of rails I used on this machine (3.2.9)

Comment: No, we mean if the sqlite3 binary is installed. The gem named sqlite3 is merely an adapter written in ruby. Go to your command line and type `sqlite3 --version`. If you get an error message, it is probably not installed.

Comment: You can find precompiled binaries here: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: I have exact the same problem. I compiled sqlite3.{exe,dll,lib}, and successfully install sqlite3 gem using mingw. "sqlite3 --version" returns "3.7.16.2 2013-04-12 11:52:43 cbea02d93865ce0e06789db95fd9168ebac970c7". "bundle show sqlite3" returns the same as @Matteo. But I still got "sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)". btw, I am using windows 7 x86.

Comment: After moving off this project for a while, I came back to try to fix the problem.  I ended up just re-installing the ruby/rails/bundle binaries from railsinstaller.org.  This seems to fix the problem with Sqlite3 - somehow, I guess the .dll (or whatever) got corrupted and needed to be reinstalled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem. This won't directly answer your question but I solved it by simply  installing the whole set using http://railsinstaller.org/ and it all works

Following are all the packages installed by railsinstaller:

- Ruby 1.9.3-p392
- Rails 3.2
- Bundler
- Git
- Sqlite
- TinyTDS
- SQL Server
- Support
- DevKit

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and a hard time to solve it. 
I was helped by these page 
[knapsack sqlite installer from Luis Lavena](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/rubyinstaller/gedIaMryCFQ)
and this one
https://github.com/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/issues/82

The first page was almost all right except I had this error :

```
checking for sqlite3_libversion_number() in -lsqlite3... no
```

The second link which gave me the solution; instead of

```
c:\sqlite3x86>gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby --  --with-sqlite3-dir=C:/sqlite3x86
```

I had to type

```
c:\sqlite3x86>gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby --  --with-sqlite3-lib=C:/sqlite3x86/lib --with-sqlite3-include=C:/sqlite3x86/include
```

As you might have guessed, I put the knapsack sqlite3 build by Luis Lavena in a directory called sqlite3x86