# 'require': can not load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Getting this error while learning tutorial from this site.

http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app#sec-demo_users_resource

tried to run this rails command on windows

**rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string**

and getting such error as:

```
> .../lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in 'require':cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native(LoadError)
>../lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in rescue in <top(required) >
>../bundler/runtime.rb:72:in 'require'
>.../bundler/runtime.rb:72:in block (2 level)
>from bin/rails:4: in 'require'
>from bin/rails:4: in <main>
```

I have already tried other answers like adding directory of sqlite to PATH..(its already there C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.0.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32)..

sqlite3(1.3.7-x86-mingw32 )is there in my gem list but still getting this error.
I have also tried to put sqlite3ext.h and sqlite3.h into /ext folder but its not working

tried this command 
gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-sqlite3-dir=C:/path/to/sqlite3
no results

here is the Content of my database.yml 
here is the database.yml file contents

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

**UPDATE**:
As adviced by one the user which really help me " you'll run into several problems that will be frustrating purely because on Windows. If you can't remove Windows, download Virtual Box and use a Linux Distro on it. It will make life much easier for you." Switching to Linux resolved everything. thanks https://stackoverflow.com/users/1092260/althaf-hameez for this advice.

Comment: Can you paste your database.yml (please hide any sensitive information such as passwords and IP addresses) and your Gemfile

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire i have added it my post.please look at it and tell me me where is the fault.

Comment: Add your Gemfile as well. However off-topic I see that you are learning on Windows, you'll run into several problems that will be frustrating purely because on Windows. If you can't remove Windows, download Virtual Box and use a Linux Distro on it. It will make life much easier for you.

Comment: @AlthafHamez..thanks i was thinking the same..i won't be using this windows for any future development..its really frustrating for me..

Comment: As advised, use linux it way better (if you feel comfortable using it) And for your question I see only one solution: verify in your Genfil that you include the sqlite gem

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire thanks i have already switch to linux but since then i just stuck with another problem ..please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/25864376?noredirect=1  
 see if you can do something about it..

Answer (score 2):

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16748607/2466276.

My actions:
1. Download http://packages.openknapsack.org/sqlite/sqlite-3.7.15.2-x86-windows.tar.lzma
2. Unpack to C:\Knapsack\x86
3. gem uninstall sqlite3
4. gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir=C:/Knapsack/x86