# cannot load sqlite3/sqlite3_native after a rake db:migrate why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, railstutorial.org

I am following a ruby on rails tutorial. I have not been able to find an answer that works for this problem yet. I am on Windows 8 running Ruby 2.0 what could be causing this?

```
$ rake db:create
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
```

Any possible fixes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18273916/1026898 ?  You haven't given us any information about what you have tried so we don't know where to start helping you.

Comment: @Ecnalyr I think you have posted the link to my question and trust me I have followed exactly the same what was written their and It simply don't work. please don't encourage people to keep using Windows for Development works.

Comment: @Abhinay I don't think stackoverflow is a forum for criticizing someone's preferred method for doing something.  It is a place for helping others answer questions they have about something.  This user did not ask if they should or should not use Windows for Rails development, I was just trying to help guide them to an answer (although Ruby/Rails support on Windows is very sparse and relatively unnecessary since Linux (@user3408293 your life will be easier if you switch to Linux for Rails development) is free and will run on any computer that can run Windows).

Comment: @Ecnalyr Yeah, I think you are right but its because of the frustration which i had while using Windows but I do agree with you but at the same time you can not complain about the smoothness you get on linux for this kind of developments,and also I don't want people to spend their most of the time looking for some window generated problems, which are not at all related to Rails learning.
I don't want them to make the same mistake which I have done.
Even if your able to resolve all of the Windows generated issues, Its not going to help you understand Rails. I hope now you got it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by simply installing the latest versions on the SQLite3 and Eventmachine gems:
https://rubygems.org/gems/eventmachine
http://rubygems.org/gems/sqlite3-ruby

Answer (score 0):

If you have extracted "exe"s and "dll"s from [Sqlite download link](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) to Ruby's bin folder and still have this problem. Try this:

`bundle update`

`gem uninstall sqlite3`

Given a choice between multiple versions of sqlite3,  choose last option 'All versions'. Enter last number here

> Select gem to uninstall:
>   1. sqlite3-1.3.13
>   2. sqlite3-1.3.13-x64-mingw32
>   3. All versions
>   >`3`
>   .
>   .
>   If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
>   Continue with Uninstall? [yN]
>   >
>   `y`

`gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby`

`rails db:create`

This should work.

Read through this [link](http://wikiprogramming.org/linux/ruby-2-5-1-windows-fix-cannot-load-such-file-sqlite3-sqlite3_native-loaderror/) for more explanation if above works for you.